# PHP programmatic and automated synchronization of ms access with MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, ms-access, synchronization, automation

At work we have a commercial access control system monitoring who enters/exits the building. This system stores a log into a MS Access file on the server where it is installed. 
The company has not released an API for this system so I cannot get the system to store the data elsewhere.

We have an intranet site built on CakePHP/MySQL. There I want to implement a section that will provide reports to HR using the data from that system.
However I'm stuck trying to figure out how to programmatically and automatically import and keep synchronized the data from the MS Access into the MySQL database.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of keeping these things in sync, I would simply query the Access database as necessary.  I think you will end up with a much more reliable system this way.

**Edit:**  If you really wanted to, there are [commercial solutions](http://www.datanamic.com/datadiff-crossdb/index.html) for this.  As long as you only need to go one direction, it should be doable.  Again though, not rcommended.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. Could you please explain abit further? What do you mean when you say query the MS Access database? Can I connect directly to it via PHP so I can show a report on our intranet? Im not sure what you meant.

Comment: Also please note that ms access is sitting on an old pc that was converted to a windows server just for the employee Access monitoring system.The intranet is sitting on a different server on Linux/Apanche.

Comment: Yes, you can connect to the Access database directly.  You would do this over ODBC using PDO:  http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-PDO.html#4.7  Since your web application is on a Linux box, you will need the appropriate ODBC driver.  I believe there are a few options... this one came up after some Googling:  http://www.easysoft.com/products/data_access/odbc-access-driver/index.html